# strtok() with realloc() weird behaviour

Tags: c, realloc, strtok

I have the following program written in C:

```
    ...
    char *answer = NULL;
    char *pch = strtok(phrase, " "); // phrase is a string with possibly many words
    while (pch) {
        char *tmp = translate_word(pch); // returns a string based on pch
        void *ptr = realloc(answer, sizeof(answer) + sizeof(tmp) + 1000); // allocate space to answer
        if (!ptr) // If realloc fails
             return -1;
        strcat(answer, tmp); // append tmp to answer
        pch = strtok(NULL, " "); // find next word
    }
    ...
```

The problem is that strtok() shows weird behavior, it returns a word that does not exist in the *phrase* string but is part of the *answer* string.

On the other hand, when I change the following line:

```
void *ptr = realloc(answer, sizeof(answer) + sizeof(tmp) + 1000);
```

to:

```
void *ptr = realloc(answer, sizeof(answer) + sizeof(tmp) + 1);
```

strok() works as expected.

How is it possible that realloc() affects strtok() in this case? They do not even use the same variables. Looking forward to your insights.

Comment: `sizeof(answer)` and `sizeof(tmp)` - this isn't doing what you think. Besides, `realloc` doesn't null terminate `answer` as needed for `strcat` to work.

Comment: `realloc` `free`s `answer` after it reallocates it, so you should use `strcat(ptr, tmp)`.

Comment: regarding: the expression in the call to `realloc()`  `sizeof(tmp)`:  `tmp` is a pointer, so depending on your underlying hardware and certain compiler options that value will be either 4 or 8 bytes, not the length of the char array pointed to by `tmp`

Comment: regarding: `void *ptr = realloc(answer, sizeof(answer) + sizeof(tmp) + 1000); // allocate space to answer
        if (!ptr) // If realloc fails
             return -1;`  1)  when `realloc()` fails, the data originally pointed to by `ptr` is lost, resulting in a memory leak.  Always assign a temporary pointer from the returned value from `realloc()`, check that temporary pointer is not NULL, then assign to the original pointer.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) Also, rather than immediately exiting when an error occurs, first call `perror( "realloc failed" );` which outputs to `stderr`, both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `realloc` function could move the memory that was previously allocated.  After the call, the pointer to the allocated memory is returned and the pointer value passed to it, if it differs, is no longer valid.  So when you call `strcat(answer, tmp);` you're potentially writing to freed memory which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and in this case it manifests as the strange output you're seeing.

After checking the return value of `realloc`, assign that value back to `answer`.

Also, `sizeof(answer)` and `sizeof(tmp)` give you the size of the pointer, not the size of what it points to.  You instead want to use `strlen` to get the length of the string then contain.  And while we're at it, lets just add 1 to this instead of 1000 because that's all you actually need.

```
    void *ptr = realloc(answer, strlen(answer) + strlen(tmp) + 1);
    if (!ptr)
         return -1;
    answer = ptr;
    strcat(answer, tmp);
```

One more issue: the first time `realloc` is called the memory is completely uninitialized.  Subsequently calling `strcat` on it depends on `answer` containing a null terminated string.  It doesn't so this also invokes undefined behavior.

This can be fixed by `malloc`-ing a single byte to start and setting it to 0, that way you start with an empty string.

```
char *answer = malloc(1);
if (!answer) return -1;
answer[0] = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

sizeof(answer) & sizeof(tmp) gives you sizes of the pointers.

You need to use strlen instead

Comment: This is only part of the answer, and not fixing the may major issue, forgetting to update the pointer after `realloc`.

Comment: @HAL9000 but it starts with it.

Answer (score 0):

additionally...

```
char *answer = NULL;
```

... either:

```
... strlen(answer) ...
strcat(answer, tmp);
```

These SHOULD fail, with a segmentation violation, but may not depending on the OS.  Dereferencing NULL is never a good idea.

In short, you need to either know you have assigned something to `answer`, or to check if answer is NULL.